# Submit dynamic value for reactive form

Tags: angular, typescript

In the below code I am trying to submit 3 values (rid, amount and reason) on form submit.

```html
 <div class="row " *ngFor="let pendingrequest of pendingrequests" >
  <form [formGroup]="pf"  (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
<div class="col" >
    <input type="hidden" formControlName="rid" name="requestid" value="{{pendingrequest.id}}" /> 

 RNuo. : {{pendingrequest.id}}
 </div>

 <div class="row">
    <div class="col">

        <input type="number"  formControlName="amount" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Amount">

    </div><div class="col">
        <input type="text" formControlName="reason" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Reason">

    </div><div class="col">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

      </div>

    </div>
  </form>
```

I am retrieving the value on the component as:

```ts
var rid = this.pf.get('rid').value ; 
var amount  = this.pf.get('amount').value ; 
var reason = this.pf.get('reason').value ;
```

I am getting Amount and Reason properly but not the rid values, which is already known to the form. It need not be submitted, that's why I kept the input type as "hidden" for rid.

Please let me know how to get this rid value at the component.

Comment: Please give a [mcve]; do you set the appropriate value in the `pf` form object?

Comment: The fact that you're using hidden input types is a smell already. Why would you need hidden inputs? Why not just keep the value in your model?

Comment: i need to get {{pendingrequest.id}} ,in the component . suing hidden input i am trying if i can get this value in the component on submit.

Answer (score 0):

using hidden field is not the angular way, because you dont need it.
by the way, here is a sample that might be helpful:

```
  <form [formGroup]="pf"  (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
 <div class="col" >
    <input type="hidden" formControlName="rid" name="rid"  />
 </div> 

 <div class="row">
    <div class="col">

        <input type="text"  formControlName="amount" class="form-control" id="amount" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Amount">

    </div><div class="col">
        <input type="text" formControlName="reason" class="form-control" id="reason" placeholder="Reason">

    </div><div class="col">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

i just set the rid parameter using Form Group:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MessageService } from 'primeng/api';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [MessageService]
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular';


  constructor(private messageService: MessageService) { 
    this.pf.patchValue({rid: 10}); 
  }

pf = new FormGroup({
    rid: new FormControl(''),
    amount: new FormControl(''),
    reason: new FormControl('')
  });

onSubmit(){
  console.warn(this.pf.value);
}
}
```

see this example in [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-primeng?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)